# How to merge / join line segments by attribute and split at intersection

Tags: qgis, line, merge, attribute-joins, spatial-join

I have a complex network of line features with a lot of attributes (and unique IDs). Many features have the exact same values (exept the ID). I need to join all features with the same attribute which are next to each other.
[image: that's what I have: an example network, many features with same values and attributes]

[image: That's what I Want: the lines are merged together]

that's what I have: an example network, many features with same values and attributes:
That's what I Want: the lines are merged together.

I want to merge them by topology: a line should be joined with a touching one. But: where more than 2 are touching (intersection) they should not be merged.

I tried:

1. dissolve, but then they are all joined, even when far away. then I tried to split up with "multi to single part" but then I came back to where I started.
2. Join Lines does what I want but not automatically and it's too much to select and join them by hand

Ideal would be a function that merges by 1.aligned neighbour (if more than 1, e.g. at intersection: no join) and 2. by same attribute value

It is very similiar to posted problems:
[Join line segments sharing a common attribute, using GDAL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151187/join-line-segments-sharing-a-common-attribute-using-gdal)
; 
[How to join segments of a line in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203065/how-to-join-segments-of-a-line-in-qgis)

But those have not been answered to a point where the issue is solved.

Comment: I am not sure if this can help you or not but try to use v.build.polylines under GRASS: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.build.polylines.html. I do not have same case to test, but you can give it a try.

Comment: It splits up right at intersections, so that's good, but it merges lines with different attributes together so I end up with stacked multilines